# How to trigger mail function when submit button clicked

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an application to send emails when a button is clicked. I tried to use isset function to do that. But my code doesn't work well.  How do I fix it?

Demo below:

```
<!-- <button name="sendemail">send</button> -->
<input type="submit"  value="send"/>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
?>
<?php

// multiple recipients
// $to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', ';   
// $to .= 'wez@example.com';
$to="example@outlook.com";
// subject
$subject = 'test01';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
</body>
</html>
';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";



    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No `name` attribute for the submit-button, and is the button placed inside a form (meaning is it sent over POST in the first place)? Also, this `?>
<?php` is really just a waste of space. You should also check if the mail is actually sent, which you currently are not doing.

Comment: @Qirel and PHP closing tag ?> is a plain bad

Comment: @VladimirHraban ...huh? How do you mean?

Comment: @Qirel It is a bad practice to include the closing tag after the code as there may be unintended whitespaces after ?>. And they will be output to the user (for instance, causing headers already sent warning)

Comment: I know that, and the point I was trying to make is that it's redundant in the first place - to close then open the PHP-tag directly after one another. In this particular case it wouldn't matter, because there is output prior to it anyway (and from what I can see, no headers or anything like that). :-) @VladimirHraban

Comment: @Qirel Sure, I was not arguing, just thought it may be useful to mention that ?> is needless in the end of the file as well. Probably was not clear enough :-)

Comment: @VladimirHraban At the very end, no - but there are many cases where escaping PHP is useful ;-) Seems like we agree, just misunderstood some. :p Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the `name` attribute for your `input` element, and the `input` element need to be in a form. Also, the `$_POST['submit']` should be in lowercase to keep it consistent.

You should also check to see if `mail()` is sent successfully. `mail()` will return `true` when sent and `false` if not sent.

**Just a note**, the actual sending of mail will depend on your hosting/ server, even if it returns `true`, it does not necessarily mean that the mail is sent.

Find out more about `mail()` at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.

The following code should work:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

// NO Change from your original code

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

    // You can change this to whatever you want PHP to do when mail is successfully sent
    echo 'Mail successfully sent';

} else {

    // You can change this to whatever you want PHP to do when mail failed to send
    echo 'Mail failed to send';

}

?>
```

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to fire an email on click of the Send Email button

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Send details to college" />
    <input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="1" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))
{
    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo 'Email Sent.';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to address here. First, your input button doesn't do anything, because it isn't a part of a form. So you either have to use some sort of JavaScript or just a HTML form to submit the button to, so we can process it in PHP. A simple form is done like this below. Note the `metohd="POST"`, this allows us to gather the information from the `$_POST`-array in PHP later on (by default forms are set to use GET).

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send!" />
</form>
```

This form will send the data over the POST-array, to the same page it's placed on, so place your PHP here as well.

Secondly, you did not have a `name` attribute in your submit-button, and since PHP uses the names rather than the IDs (like JavaScript does), you need to add this. This can be seen in the code-snippet above.

Further, you never check if the mail was actually sent or not. You should never take anything for granted.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /* add headers, messages and such here */

    // Check if the mail is being sent from the server
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) [
        // Mail was sent! Great!
    } else {
        // It failed sending the mail
    }
}
?>
```